# How to stop a While loop in LabView using a timer

Tags: labview

I am doing a project for Uni and I need the while loop to stop after 6s. So I did the usual set up the wait(ms) to wait 6000ms and then compared it to 6000const to get a bool value of TRUE which should have stopped my loop, but it didn't. So I was wondering if you had any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Posting a picture of your current code always helps the question. Select all of your code on the diagram and then choose "Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection". This gives you a PNG file that includes metadata that others can use to drag onto their block diagrams and recreate your code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want a "Wait" function -- that function halts execution until that node finishes, which means your While Loop will only execute 1 time, and that 1 time will last 6000 ms.

What you want is the Tick Count function.

*You can drag this image out of your browser (some browsers may require you to save the PNG to disk first) onto your block diagram to recreate the code (if you have LV 2016 or later, as noted by the version number in the top-right corner). This image was created using "Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection".*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option to resolve you problem can be using a timed loop. These are specifically designed for timing tasks. The benefit of a timed loop is that you have more accurate control over when it stops. The proposed while loop (from srm) will stop after 6 seconds + the time it needs to finish the code. The "downside" of a timed loop is that it behaves more like a for loop where each loop takes a specific time interval, ussualy I find that more a benefit than a downside:

[image: while loop and timed loop VI snippet]

I also put in the previous suggested solution (from srm) for comparison. On my pc the timed loop stops with ms accuracy while the while loop has a delay of several tens of miliseconds.

Comment: I like this revised approach as it has plenty of flexibility. However the limitation is that if there is a lot of 'code' in the loop and it takes longer than the loop time then the calculation of how many loops to do is no longer valid and the total runtime will be longer than the user specified. If I can figure out an improvement which considers actual loop time, I'll add it to this thread.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. About the mentioned limitation, the timed loop has the option to check this. There is a "Finished Late" statement that let's you check whether the loop completed within the allotted time. You also have the "Mode" option where you can specify how the loop should handle late executions. See: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/timed_loop/

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason your bool value is false is that the output of the Wait (ms) VI is not the number of milliseconds the VI waited but "milliseconds timer" which is the number of milliseconds since windows booted up or something to that effect. It's the same number you'd get if you ran Tick Count (ms) VI the instant the wait VI finished.

Others are correct to point out that a 6 second wait in the loop will prevent your loop from completing execution and repeating until the 6 seconds are over.